# Image Preloading Canvas in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, canvas, preload

I have, to the best of my knowledge, preloaded all of my images successfully. In FireFox, everything renders just fine, but it refuses to show up in Chrome. I've already run into other random quirks with the webkit browsers, and I assume this is just one of them. Here's the applicable code (I apologize for the length, just being verbose. Most of it is quite straightforward, I assure you).

initResources() is called from the $(document).ready() function, where canvas is also properly initialized.

The specific issue appears to be the gameboard. The X's and O's (it's tictactoe...) appear fine, but the gameboard refuses to appear on the canvas in Chrome alone. Works in all other browsers. Chrome's developer tools insists they're being loaded via Network tab, console is showing everything it should. Thank you.

[EDIT: Just now failed in Firefox as well. May have been a cache issue, at which point I'm even more confused]

```
var canvas, context, playerPiece, aiPiece;
var x = new Image();
var o = new Image();
var gameBoard = new Image();
var numResources = 3;   // Total number of resources to wait for loading
var curResources = 0;

function initResources() {
    // Get all our resources ready to go
    x.height = 130;
    x.width = 130;
    x.onload = isLoaded();
    x.src = "images/gamepieceX.png";

    o.height = 130;
    o.width = 130;
    o.onload = isLoaded();// = curResources++;
    o.src = "images/gamepieceO.png";

    gameBoard.height = 500;
    gameBoard.width = 500;
    gameBoard.onload = isLoaded(); //= curResources++;
    gameBoard.src = "images/gameBoard.png";
}

function isLoaded() {
    curResources++;
    console.log("Loaded resource! Total: " + curResources);
    if(curResources == numResources) {
        console.log("All loaded up! Moving on!");
        gameSetup();
    }
}

function gameSetup() {
    // Draw our board and assign a piece
    console.log("Setting up game!");
    playerPiece = x;
    aiPiece = o;

    // Draw gameboard
    context.drawImage(gameBoard, 0, 0);
    console.log(gameBoard);

    canvas.addEventListener ("mousedown", mouseClicked, false);
}
```

Comment: I have heard the only reliable way to utilize `img.onload` is to initialize it through a `<img onload=""/>`, that `var img = new Image();` won't fire the `onload` consistently.

Comment: You're running the `isLoaded` function inline, not when the image is actually loaded. I think that you want `.onload = isLoaded` (no parentheses) Not sure if this is related, just pointing it out.

Comment: Yes, Xymostech, I believe this is the issue! I just spotted the same thing before coming back here and seeing these comments. Thank you!

Comment: @DanielGast No problem. It's always the small things that get you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was calling the functions inline instead of for a callback for .onload on each image. This was firing off the game initialization before the image was loaded. Thanks to those who commented, but I saw this only moments after posting here :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link to a chrome bug that might have something to do with this.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245296

Instead of using

```
new Image()
```

create an image element the old fashioned way

```
document.createElement("img")
```